# Colorbox not showing border or buttons, other problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

I've seen a few issues regarding this same problem, and I've tried everything suggested in them but so far nothing has worked.

I'm loading the css/js files in the order that they should be: Colorbox.css->jQuery.js->Colorbox.js (there other css and js files being loaded in between those).

I'm launching the colorbox via script:

```
$().ready(function() {
    $('.dgallery').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('a[class=dgallery]').colorbox({
            rel:'dgallery', 
            slideshow:true,
            preloading:true,
            slideshowSpeed:4000
        }).click();
    });
});
```

And the HTML (.dgallery has display:none in the stylesheet):

```
<a class="dgallery" href="/assets/images/VideoSlides/slide1.png"></a>
<a class="dgallery" href="/assets/images/VideoSlides/slide2.png"></a>
<a class="dgallery" href="/assets/images/VideoSlides/slide3.png"></a>
```

The problems seem to vary depending on the browser:

- Chrome shows the lightbox and images, but it's missing the border and buttons. Occasionally, I've seen the lightbox open and it say "Image failed to load" but then continues with the slideshow and it works (still missing the border and buttons though).
- Firefox opens the lightbox which looks just fine. But it just sits there with the "loading" graphic and never loads the images.
- IE does the same thing as Chrome. Sometimes I've seen the browser flash white before it opens the lightbox.

I'm not really sure what else I'm missing.

Comment: Why are you using "click()" instead of the normal colorbox usage?

Comment: Which `click()` are you referring to? The one after the .colorbox({}) I ended up removing.

Comment: The first one. $('.dgallery').click(function ... Colorbox will automatically prevent the default for you. have you trying removing such line?

Comment: Yes, I've tried removing the first line; Doesn't make any difference. I'm doing it that way because 1) The colorbox is being fired from an onclick() event in an <a> tag and, 2) the above method is the only way that I've been able to get colorbox to even appear and, 3) It's a method detail on the colorbox website here: http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/faq#faq-click